# Include related data from second collection in collection.find

Tags: meteor

I have two collections, foo and bar. They look like this:

```
foo: {name: SOMENAME, barId: MONGO_ID}
bar: {name: ANOTHERNAME}
```

I search the foo collection using this query:

```
searchFoo = function(query) {
    var re = new RegExp(query, "i");
    FooCollection.find({
        name: {
            $regex: re
        }
    });
};
```

All found `foo` items are shown in a list. This works nicely. Problem is, how do I also show the `foo`items where the query matches the name of the connected `bar` item? I do not want to include `bar` in the `foo` document, if possible.

I know there are no joins in MongoDB. I know that I can get the name of `bar`by doing a second query when I have a `foo`. But what is a sensible pattern for a search here?

Comment: You'll need to run it twice, once against your foo collection and once against your bar collection.  Without joins in mongo, no matter what pattern you use you're simply landing up at the same place.  I would publishing both cursors from a single publish function, to make it easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `$regex` unless its a direct (with the mongodb `$regex`) [syntax](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex).

This should work:

```
searchFoo = function(query) {
    var re = new RegExp(query, "i");
    return FooCollection.find({
        name: re
    });
};
```

as should this:

```
searchFoo = function(query) {
    return FooCollection.find({
        name: { $regex: query, $options: "i" }
    });
};
```

Additionally to link up your bar query do a transform instead of regex:

```
FooCollection.find({name:"SOMENAME"}, {transform:function(doc) {
    if(doc.barId) doc.bar = FooCollection.findOne(doc.barId)
    return doc;
}});
```

This should give you the result (after a `fetch` or if you parse through the cursor)

```
[{
  name: SOMENAME, barId: MONGO_ID,
  bar : { name: ANOTHERNAME}
}]
```

More information about transforms can be found in the meteor docs under [Collections](http://docs.meteor.com/#collections)

Comment: Hmm, that wasn't it, sorry... My goal is to be able to search for ANOTHER and find the foo document. Still, transform is nice, but it does not do that, does it?

Answer (score 0):

Transform should work the other way around too:

```
BarCollection.find({name:"ANOTHERNAME"}, {transform:function(barDoc) {
    return FooCollection.findOne({barId:barDoc._id});
}});
```

Comment: Yes, but still does not give me a query where I can search for "ANOTHER" and "SOME" and both times get the foo item (optionally with the bar item attached). That was my goal.